# How to ensure revoked Celery task never run after all worker process go down and come back

Tags: celery

Here's the use case.

Day 1: Invoke a celery task with countdown 7 days from now
Day 2: Revoke this task
Day 3: Upgrade happens, so all worker processes are down and then come back up again in some time

I have tested similar scenario, I figured out that there is a revoke list for processes that are revoked in all worker processes. But the message (corresponding to task) remains in that worker process to which the task is delegated. So once all worker processes go down, the revoke list information is lost too.

I want to understand if that's the case, then after all workers come back up, then wouldn't that process start executing without getting cancelled/revoked? I am saying so because the revoke list information resides (from what I feel) only in worker processes, and not in broker.

Can some one please confirm this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct - Celery workers keep the list of revoked tasks in-memory and if all workers are restarted, the list disappears. Quoting the Celery user guide on workers:

> Revoking tasks works by sending a broadcast message to all the workers, the workers then keep a list of revoked tasks in memory. When a worker starts up it will synchronize revoked tasks with other workers in the cluster.
>
> The list of revoked tasks is in-memory so if all workers restart the list of revoked ids will also vanish. If you want to preserve this list between restarts you need to specify a file for these to be stored in by using the –statedb argument to celery worker:

For more information, see the section on Persistent Revokes in the Celery User Guide.